# MongoDB full text search vs Lucene?

Tags: mongodb, lucene

How does MongoDB's full text search compare to Lucene at the present time? The reason for the question is due to my indeterminacy to:

a) use mongo's FTS implementation in production since it was still in beta around 6 months ago

and

b) because lucene uses Java which will introduce yet another moving part.

Comment: Just to make it clear, Lucene doesn't only work in Java environment. .NET and C++ versions are also available.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Without wandering into a long topic that would probably not be suited for a programming forum, I'll try and cover this basically, but still try and cover the points.

The main thing to consider when jumping into a broad comparison is this: *"How does 'XYZ' relational database engine full text search stack up against Lucene"*.

So if you consider that, and have had experience with the built in "full text" capabilities of those products then those are the apples you **should** be comparing with the MongoDB "full text" apples.

In short, MongoDB offers basic full text capabilities, not much different to those found in relational products. As mentioned in **a:)**, the facilities are new, but better than what was there before, which was nothing.

On **b:)**, Lucene, and derivatives/ counterparts (Solr / ElasticSearch, etc) should be considered a different animal altogether. Where you **need** advanced tokenizing and stemming, built in facilities for *"More like this"* and *facet counts* on searches. In those cases the separate product is a required necessity.

Of course there are several solutions around for indexing data from MongoDB stores in Lucene etc, and even customizing this process is not hard. But it is maintaining another moving part in your infrastructure.

So I don't really see this as a need to **compare** MongoDB text search with Lucene, because *ultimately* they exist to do different things, it's just a matter of what you **need** for your application. Choose the solution that is best for you.

The only thing to add is that, the Lucene (and derivative) family are great products. Do not shy away from giving them a go, at least to evaluate. The points from before is there is a lot more power there than any "Standard Database Text Search". Furthermore the admin and learning curve are generally "not as hard as you think". Have a play, it may be worth implementing.

Comment: @heinob Seems to come up a bit. General rule of thumb, don't compare a "chainsaw" to "garden shears", and don't use a "chainsaw" to trim a hedge, if you **want** to cut down a tree, then go ahead. But I'm sure you already agree ;)

Comment: ...and to decide, which one is best, it is alway a good start, to once have had both in your hands before.

Comment: May be this link helps to get quick figures - http://www.openwebspider.org/2015/04/03/full-text-search-mysql-vs-mongodb-vs-sphinx/

Answer (score 17):

**To cut a long story short:** Yes, Lucene (Solr/ElasticSearch) is another moving part. And you have to know, that I hate adding moving parts to my system. I do anything to avoid it. But, if you want to support a search within your application that goes a little beyond a simple (simple!) full-text-search **then you need Lucene**. I promise you, when you have got used to it, you never (never!) gonna miss it again.

So the simple recommendation is: Try it out! You will not regret it.

Comment: Agreed. Why not indeed.