# Can mongodb create index when inserting data?

Tags: mongodb

I've read the docs of mongodb and get to know that if I want to do text search I should use `create index`. But can I create index for each data during insert process? If I can, how should I do?

Comment: Yes, if you already have done a create index on that field, a new document insertion will update the db indexes with an entry for this document

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The index is created once for a *collection*, i.e. for [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#index-feature-text) do this

```
db.yourCollection.createIndex({yourText:"text"})
```

The index is updated automatically on every insert operation. You don't have to do this manually but have it in mind. This is what makes insert operations expensive. The more indexes you have the longer it takes to insert a document and update all of them.

If you want a link to the documentation, this topic is faced [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-performance/#indexes).

Comment: So after I did the `db.yourCollection.createIndex({yourText:"text"})
` , I don't have to worry about the index thing, every time I insert one data system will give it an index automatically?

Comment: The index is an in-memory datastructure (i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) created once with `createIndex` that help the system to find the right document faster than sequentially reading every document from disc. This data structure needs to be updated which is done on every insert. Do not think of an index as in arrays: array[index]. It's a tree, not a list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do I have any solution to do text search in mongo and reduce the cost of insert operations?

Comment: a full-text index as described is the way to go. You shouldn't be afraid of, just be aware of the cost. It's still the fastest built-in option you got. But depending on requirement, you might use a dedicated full test search engine like Lucene, but that comes with a cost either, see also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871188/mongodb-full-text-search-vs-lucene

Comment: Got it. But when I use `db.BioSample.createIndex({"$**":"text"})
` to create indexes on multiple fields, the response contain one statement that `"createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
`. I've look through docs, but I can't find what's this mean?

Comment: This indicates that collection was created when the index was created. This happens, when you create an index on a collection that does not exist yet.

Comment: Ok. I thought this indicates whether it can give indexes when inserting new data. So there is no relationship between the two thing, right?